# js TreeWalker and/or document.createRange() not picking up single element

Tags: javascript, html, range

I have a div with a single inner node:

```
<section id="Source" class="source">
  <div>
    test
  </div>
</section>
```

and I am trying to get its content with `document.createRange()` and `document.createTreeWalker()` as per below:

```
function findEndNode(source, maxHeight) {
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(source);

  var nodes = document.createTreeWalker(
    source,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
    null,
    null
  );

  while (node = nodes.nextNode()) {
    range.setEndBefore(nodes.currentNode);
    const {
      height
    } = range.getBoundingClientRect();
    const rangeHeight = height;

    if (maxHeight <= rangeHeight) {
      console.log('out of  bounds');
      const newNode = nodes.previousNode();
      range.setEndBefore(nodes.currentNode);
      break;
    } else {
      console.log('within bounds');
      continue;
    }
  }

  return range;
};
```

But somewhere along the way, the innermost node gets lost.

As you can see in the full code (included in snippet) the "test" span remains inside the Source, whereas it should be moved to Clone.

```js
const source = document.getElementById('Source');
const target = document.getElementById('Target');
const wrapper = document.getElementById('Wrapper');

wordWrap(source);
splitContent(source, target, wrapper);
//splitContent(source, target, wrapper);

function splitContent(source, target, wrapper) {
  const {
    height
  } = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  const maxHeight = height;

  const range = document.createRange();
  const endNode = findEndNode(source, maxHeight);
  
  range.setStart(source, 0);
  range.setEnd(endNode.endContainer, endNode.endOffset);

  const content = range.extractContents();
  const clone = target.cloneNode(false);
  clone.id = 'Clone';
  clone.appendChild(content);
  wrapper.appendChild(clone);

  const hasChildren = source.hasChildNodes();
};


function findEndNode(source, maxHeight) {
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(source);

  var nodes = document.createTreeWalker(
    source,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
    null,
    null
  );

  while (node = nodes.nextNode()) {
    range.setEndBefore(nodes.currentNode);
    const {
      height
    } = range.getBoundingClientRect();
    const rangeHeight = height;

    if (maxHeight <= rangeHeight) {
      console.log('out of  bounds');
      const newNode = nodes.previousNode();
      range.setEndBefore(nodes.currentNode);
      break;
    } else {
      console.log('within bounds');
      continue;
    }
  }

  return range;
};



function wordWrap(element) {
  var nodes = document.createTreeWalker(
    element,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    null,
    null
  );
  var node;
  while (node = nodes.nextNode()) {
    var p = node.parentNode;
    var text = node.nodeValue;
    var m;
    while (m = text.match(/^(\s*)(\S+)/)) {
      text = text.slice(m[0].length);
      p.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(m[1]), node);
      var word = p.insertBefore(document.createElement('span'), node);
      word.appendChild(document.createTextNode(m[2]));
      word.className = 'word';
    }
    node.nodeValue = text;
  }
}
```

```css
section {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

.target {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px dashed green;
  margin: 20px;
}

.source {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
}
#Clone {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section id="Source" class="source">
  <div>
    test
  </div>
</section>

<div id="Target" class="target">
</div>

<section id="Wrapper">
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your endoffset is off. In `findEndNodes` When you find the node your current code assumes the number of the offset is one less than is necessary, this is because you're using setEndBefore when you should use setEndAfter.

```js
const source = document.getElementById('Source');
const target = document.getElementById('Target');
const wrapper = document.getElementById('Wrapper');

wordWrap(source);
splitContent(source, target, wrapper);
//splitContent(source, target, wrapper);

function splitContent(source, target, wrapper) {
  const {
    height
  } = target.getBoundingClientRect();
  const maxHeight = height;

  const range = document.createRange();
  const endNode = findEndNode(source, maxHeight);
  
  range.setStart(source, 0);
  range.setEnd(endNode.endContainer, endNode.endOffset);

  const content = range.extractContents();
  const clone = target.cloneNode(false);
  clone.id = 'Clone';
  clone.appendChild(content);
  wrapper.appendChild(clone);

  const hasChildren = source.hasChildNodes();
};


function findEndNode(source, maxHeight) {
  const range = document.createRange();
  range.selectNodeContents(source);

  var nodes = document.createTreeWalker(
    source,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
    null,
    null
  );

  while (node = nodes.nextNode()) {
    range.setEndAfter(nodes.currentNode);
    const {
      height
    } = range.getBoundingClientRect();
    const rangeHeight = height;

    if (maxHeight <= rangeHeight) {
      console.log('out of  bounds');
      const newNode = nodes.previousNode();
      range.setEndAfter(nodes.currentNode);
      break;
    } else {
      console.log('within bounds');
      continue;
    }
  }

  return range;
};



function wordWrap(element) {
  var nodes = document.createTreeWalker(
    element,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    null,
    null
  );
  var node;
  while (node = nodes.nextNode()) {
    var p = node.parentNode;
    var text = node.nodeValue;
    var m;
    while (m = text.match(/^(\s*)(\S+)/)) {
      text = text.slice(m[0].length);
      p.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(m[1]), node);
      var word = p.insertBefore(document.createElement('span'), node);
      word.appendChild(document.createTextNode(m[2]));
      word.className = 'word';
    }
    node.nodeValue = text;
  }
}
```

```css
section {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 11pt;
}

.target {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 2px dashed green;
  margin: 20px;
}

.source {
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 20px;
}
#Clone {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section id="Source" class="source">
  <div>
    test
  </div>
</section>

<div id="Target" class="target">
</div>

<section id="Wrapper">
</section>
```